# work and chemical bonds

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

If breaking bonds is endothermic (takes energy), and work is force over a distance-

Would breaking bonds require "work"? Or do we only need heat energy? I'm trying to understand how to relate work to chemistry.

Comment: Macroscopic heat means microscopic work, that's really one and the same, only perspective is different.

Comment: You start with a very narrow definition of work.

Comment: When modeling a Diesel engine you might think of the compression step as being adiabatic, in which case you are using work to heat the gas which ultimately results in combustion. As matt_black suggests, you have to consider who is doing the work.